# Uncaught DOMException

Tags: frames

Migrating my website to a secure server, a frame is being blocked by browsers because of a security issue which doesn't happen on my existing website, which is hosted on an http server.  [Google Chrome Developer Console screen shot][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQkpr.jpg

The page should load a calendar, but it does not do so.

I'm not a coding expert, and don't know how to resolve this.  The issue happens when loading this page:

[Page which generates DOMException](https://mauitradewinds.com/RezEasy/mobile/0001/cl0001.html)

However, the site under development is hosted on a non-public server.  In order to access it, the hosts file on a Windows platform would need to have this code added: 199.168.187.45  mauitradewinds.com www.mauitradewinds.com secure.mauitradewinds.com   m.mauitradewinds.com

Without adding that code to the hosts file, a browser would be redirected to my existing http site, which is not where the issue is happening.

I'd be grateful for guidance on how to eliminate this frame blocking.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have a protocol conflict between your iframe and your main page.

Your main page is accessing through http and the iframe through https.

Your existing website most probably has a redirect from http to https which is why the issue is not happening on the existing site.

Comment: Thank you Julian.  I don't believe the main page is accessing through http.  That only appears to happen if the Windows hosts file has not been modified, as specified in the original posting.  If the hosts file is modified, and the page in question is loaded, the source can be seen to have only https references.  The existing website does not redirect to https.  Looking at the DOMException in Chrome Developer Console, it seems that the "cross origin" content may be in the form of ports which are appended to the URL in a frame.  I don't understand why or how those ports are added.

Comment: For the cross origin error to trigger either the port, protocol or domain must be different. If anyone of those is not the same in the iframe as the host then a cross origin error will occur.

Answer (score 0):

A web developer solved this by observing that adding www to the URL would prevent the DOMException, and allow page frame content to load.